# Native input hint isn't center aligned in iOS safari browser

Tags: html, css, ios, safari

Input hint isn't center aligned. Native input and native hint message in iOS safari browser. It's working well in 
 Xcode simulator, but broken on iOS devices. Same with english lang interface.

[input hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOjBU.png)

```
    <input 
        class="bind__input"
        id="bind__input"
        name="email"
        type="text"
        pattern="^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$"
        placeholder="example@mail.ru"
        required
    />
```

```
.bind__input {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
}
```

For example [HTML attribute: required in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required). Input fields have same issue in iOS

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Add Code

.bind__input{text-align: center;}
.bind__input::placeholder {text-align: center;}
```

Comment: It's not about placeholder.